# Выбор конструкции сетки сайта

Tags: html, css

Хотелось бы услышать адекватные мысли по поводу выбора конструкции сетки для сайта:
`float` **vs.** `inline-block`**vs.**`display: table`**vs.**`flex`
А именно причины выбора той или иной конструкции, подводные камни.....
Ориентация сайта  примерно на IE 9+, в дальнейшем возможна  поддержка и остального старья (по настроению, анализу и времени).

Comment: а чем сетка бутстрапа не по нраву?

Comment: @Борис, она в разряде `float` :-D

Comment: @Борис, честно сказать я его в глаза не видел ни разу и ближайшее время видеть не хочу.....  Нахожусь в процессе осваивания всех этих вещей и склонен на данном этапе делать все ручками и разобраться досконально что, где, когда...

Comment: тогда понятно) везде свои плюсы и свои минусы...скажу точно что флекс не советовал бы...поддержка еще не ахти...

Comment: @Борис да вот  же.... видел неплохие сайты на `display: table`,  но сам между `float` и `inline-block`.....

Comment: все от ситуации, если не бутстрап то я чаще флоаты юзаю...привычка)

Comment: У флекса давно уже отличная поддержка. Даже от префиксов можно отказаться.
А использование IE 9+.. их поддержка уже окончилась Microsoft...